# Can't get Nvidia 880M to work on my Asus G750JZ

Tags: drivers, nvidia, laptop

With the new proton hype I wanted to check out Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop.
For some reason I cant get my 880M to work/active and the intel gpu does all the work. I did read multiple treads that laptops and dual gpu's are a drama and sometimes a nice challenge. Well at this point its to much for me so I need your help on this one.

System status:
Dualboot with win10 (that I hope to dump soon)
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (on kernel v4.18.8, by ukuu)
Nvidia-driver-396
completely updated (apt update / apt full-upgrade / apt autoremove)
NVIDIA X Server Settings or nvidia settings wont start
(ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system)
While the NVIDIA GPU stat tool works with setting on SMI or Optimus with Bumblebee

Wished outcome ... a working 880M, even if it would mean to activate it by hand.

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please show content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file and `dmesg` command?

Comment: Also, what's the exact version of your nvidia driver package? I've googled around, and NVidia 396.51 and higher seems to play nicely wit 4.18 kernel. But before that, at rc1 of 4.18 kernel, [there was a breakage between NVidia kernel driver and the kernel](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/6/16/9) *(because NVidia are using unstable API "DKMS", which is a whole different story)*, and I'm unsure whether it was "solved" in the kernel or in NVidia driver.

Comment: @Hi-Angel what is the best way to add the huge amount of texts here ? (btw I got a Xorg.8.log not the 0)

Comment: I think you can paste it into some paste site, [like this one](https://lpaste.net/), and share a link.

Comment: I put them in a folder on googledrive ... <https://drive.google.com/open?id=12wDmgf3N4Vmj5ttcvZCsfSrANsA-KWFo>

Comment: and at this moment 396.54 is installed  
nvidia-driver-396/bionic,now 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]

Comment: Okay, [maybe this is relevant](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/526#issuecomment-377815369). Can you show content of `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` and `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` files? Side note: funny line in dmesg, I laughed `[    1.294502] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS`. I guess no DOS for you with this laptop 

Comment: @Hi-Angel I did upload the files in the google drive folder from before

Comment: Okay, so, at least now I see why it broke on you: I don't see nvidia396 [among packages for 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nvidia&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all), apparently you installed it from a PPA, or something. Nice, so it's not a bug in official packages. Try to copy to the `xorg.conf.nvidia` the acc. section from the comment I linked above; and also make the changes to the two paths in `bumblebee.conf`, again like in the linked comment. If it didn't help, please give me the output of `dpkg -L nvidia-graphics-drivers-396` *(or how was that package called?)*

Comment: @Hi-Angel Yeah I did all kinda stuff to install the latest driver and at some point it broke even the entire nvidia package managment (something about missing dependencies orso) ... anyway with uninstall and purge actions I got it all working again. I will look at the changes to make in the pointed out config files once I'm dont with my job. I hope after that that Steam (and its windows games) see my 880M ;) I will update asap

Comment: @Hi-Angel more seems to be working/responding but stil nothing in steam. Thanks for attempt to get things working here. I guess this is yet a other prove to me that linux is not ready for casual users and solve issues like these simply ... especially when they use nvidia and/or a laptop with hybrid gpu. I might try a clean install and see how that goes, if still nothing then I stick a little bit longer to M$ :(

Comment: Well, the steam issue is a distinct problem from the one we were solving here, your prev. 2 comments is first time you mentioned it. I assume you're referring to ability to choose a GPU to play a game on it. I'm unsure about NVidia specifically, [they like doing everything their own way](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/957981/linux/prime-render-offloading-on-nvidia-optimus/1), neither I know what Steam supposed to do. But on both of my personal and work laptops I can play a game on the other GPU with `DRI_PRIME=1` just fine. Those GPU combinations are: AMD + AMD and AMD + Intel.

Comment: To make my prev. comment a bit more clear: if I understood your problem correctly, this is either a problem specific to NVidia *(the inability to use `DRI_PRIME`)*, or one specific to Steam, which doesn't use the part of EGL or Vulkan API that allows to an app to choose a GPU to render on.

Answer (score 0):

I am a user of Asus FX553VD (also with dual graphics), and I just made everything work with bumblebee. There were significant changes in nvidia install, so majority of guides won't help you.

For different reasons `nvidia-prime` doesn't work well with some laptops, so I recommend you using `bumblebee`.

Bumblebee is a package that let's you run different packages on discrete card, and only when it get's called, card turns on, so you have nice power management.

Firstly, install bumblebee by `sudo apt install bumblebee`

If you have `nvidia-xxx` driver then you don't have to reinstall, else if you have `nvidia-driver-xxx` I couldn't get it work with bumblebee, but if you will, let me now.

Anyway, do `sudo apt purge nvidia*` - to purge your nvidia packages, and do `sudo apt install nvidia-390` - most stable version by now.

DON'T REBOOT!!!

Secondly, do `prime-select intel`, to select your intel card. Now you can reboot.

Thirdly, we have to configure our `bumblebee.conf` file, which is located in `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`. You can do this by `sudo nano /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`.

In `[bumblebeed]` section change `Driver=` to `Driver=nvidia`.

In `[driver-nvidia]` section change your `KernelDriver=` to `KernelDriver=nvidia`, `LibraryPath=..` to `LibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` and `XorgModulePath=...` to `XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input`

Now, go to `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf`, and blacklist `nvidia-390` as earlier drivers had been, just by changing driver version.

After that look for any file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` for having `alias nvidia off`. If any does, comment it, so it look like this - `#alias nvidia off`. Also check `/lib/modprobe.d/` folder, and do the same thing.

Finally, you can reboot and try your optirun.

P.S: I was managing to get it working for a week, and just fixed everything.